# To upload a video file in angular 2 using ng2 file upload and display the video in a player in the front end

Tags: javascript, typescript, ng2-file-upload

Uploading video is easy.As I am able to get it done using the ng2 file upload .
I wanted to display the dropped video file in a player on the front end side.
any suggestions regarding this will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use  tag of html5 fot it. How you get duration of video using ng2-file-upload?